# Assign length to array after initialization in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I'm trying to figure out how to make a constructor that will create a new array with parameter `x` as the size of the array.

Here is what I mean:

```
public class ArrayClass{

public String[] elements = new String[];

public ArrayClass(int x) {
    'length of array' = x;
}
```

I tried to experiment with some of the syntax I know but couldn't figure it out.

Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Simply declare your array, and then in the constructor, specify the length:

```
public String[] elements;

public ArrayClass(int x) {
    elements = new String[x];
}
```